# Why does getting front of queue of queue of char causing a bad_alloc?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
myclass::myclass(queue<queue<char> > construction_info){
  //why does this line crash?
  queue<char> first_line_of_construction_info = construction_info.front();
  construction_info.pop();
}
```

I am reading from text files (not generated by me so I can't change the format), into a queue of queue of char. It means lines of characters. And I process that info to generate the class. However, after working in a few debug messages I realized that the first time I am getting a bad_alloc on execute (the program initialized all myclasses from text files at startup) is this line in the code.

I'm new to working with C++ and my google-fu hasn't really helped me with this problem. Does anyone have any suggestions as to where I can start solve this crash?

Simply uncommenting the class constructor is letting my program work without any crashes, obviously without generating actually useful objects of course.

Using g++ with c++11 on linux.

Edit:

Here is the full code cut from the main file:

```
int initialize_classrooms(){
  path p = "files/classrooms/";
  //files of lines of queues of chars
  //vector of vector of queue of char
  vector<queue<queue<char> > > classroom_files;
  if(exists(p)){
    for (directory_entry& x : directory_iterator(p)){
      queue<queue<char> > cur_file;

      ifstream file(x.path().filename().string());

      queue<char> cur_line;
      char ch;
      while (file >> noskipws >> ch) {
        if(!isspace(ch)){
          cur_line.push(ch);
        }else if(ch == '\n'){
          cur_file.push(cur_line);
          cur_line = queue<char>();
        }
      }
      classroom_files.push_back(cur_file); 
      cur_file = queue<queue<char> >();
      file.close();
    }
  }else{
    cout << "Classroom files are missing!" << endl;
    return 1;
  }
  cout << "Got all the way to classroom creation" << endl;
  int i = 1;
  for(auto cf : classroom_files){
    cout << "Number of loops: " << i << endl;
    i++;
    shared_ptr<classroom> cr = shared_ptr<classroom>(new classroom(cf));
  }
  cout << "Got past the classroom creation" << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: How big is the queue? `bad_alloc` normally means you've run out of memory.

Comment: How do you know the queue has something in it?  Can you get the size of the queue before trying to get an item?

Comment: @PaulRooney I have added the generation code

Comment: @JerryJeremiah oh right, construction_info.empty() does equal true. I'm looking into the generation code to see why.

Comment: Why are you using `std::queue<std::queue<char>>` in the first place?  Why not `std::queue<std::string>`? Or even just `std::string` by itself? Why are using `std::vector<std::queue>` instead of `std::vector<std::string>`? Why are you reading the file char-by-char, instead of line-by-line (such as via `std::getline()`)?  Does each individual `char` actually need to be processed individually?  Or do you need to process lines instead? Do you really need multiple layers of queues? Or just a single list of lines in a file? This code is using a lot of overhead for something that should be trivial.

Comment: @RemyLebeau other than changing the text file format (which is designed to be easily readable by humans instead of computers) or working with a bunch of substrings, or rewriting the string to get rid of the already processed information, this seemed like the best option. The files are around 8 lines long and have less than 25 characters anyways. These aren't actual long english texts but I am currently constrained in that I can not change them. Also, I am trying to experiment with C++ and learn how to use more complex structures as I am primarily a Python programmer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the goal is only to *read* the contents (of the queue at the front), then creating a (constant) reference is preferred.

```
queue<char> const& first_line_of_construction_info = construction_info.front();
            ^^^^^^
```

After "read"ing, it can be `pop`ed just as in current code.

EDIT: (Thanks to @Remy Lebeau)
Since copies are wastefule, `myclass` constructor can take `construction_info` by reference instead of by value.

```
myclass::myclass(queue<queue<char> > const& construction_info) {
                                     ^^^^^^
```

Look in the rest of your code too, you probably do not want multiple copies of these queue-of-queues floating around.

Aside: Unless otherwise constrained, instead of using a `queue<char>` for storing a line of text, consider using `std::string`.

Comment: I had assumed that my code was creating a copy of the front(). Now with your answer I understand how a const reference would work well. However, could you also tell me how I would go about creating a copy, so that I can see the difference.

Comment: The `myclass` constructor should also be taking `construction_info` by reference instead of by value so that it is actually acting on the original `queue` and not a copy.

Comment: @RemyLebeau is that because copying it is just wasteful, or are you suggesting that because of other problems?

Comment: I'm working with char queues instead of strings because the text file format is pretty horrible, and it seemed much easier to get rid of text I read so that I wouldn't have to mess with a bunch of substrings and index calculations. I'm not sure if it is the perfect reason to use them of course, but for right now I am happy with a fifo structure.

Comment: I see no reason to process a file's content char-by-char instead of line-by-line. It is very easy to parse lines, such as with `std::istringstream`. And I really don't see the need for multiple layers of queues when a single queue would suffice (and better to get rid of the queues altogether and just stick with the `vector` by itself)

Comment: @RemyLebeau Oh right, there are string streams! You are right, that would make it a bunch easier.